# Creating Custom directive do not work

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to create a custom directive..

```
 <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../Scripts/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../Scripts/DataDirectives.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body  style="overflow: hidden" >
      <div ng-app="myApp">
        <SampleData></SampleData>
      </div>
    </body>
```

In a separate Javascript File called DataDirectives.js the followung code is present..

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.directive('SampleData', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        template: '<div>Sample Div,To test angular Directives</div>'
    };
});
```

So when I run the page,I cannot see any text on that page of that of the div element.What could be wrong with my above code.
Thanks for the help in Advance... :)

Answer (score 2):

You have 2 ng-app as well as you are not following the required naming convensions

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.directive('sampleData', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    template: '<div>Sample Div,To test angular Directives</div>'
  };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp">
  <sample-data></sample-data>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

in html write directive name: sample-data

in js sampleData

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.directive('sampleData', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        template: '<div>Sample Div,To test angular Directives</div>'
    };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<body ng-app="myApp"  style="overflow: hidden" >
      <div ng-app="myApp">
        <sample-data></SampleData>
      </div>
    </body>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are defining the angular directive in your template using camelcase naming convention. The angular directive should be declared in template like `sample-data`. Then in javascript file you can reference it like `sampleData`.

Taking these into consideration, you should change the code in the following manner:

```
<div ng-app="myApp">
   <sample-data></sample-data>
</div>
```

Another alternative would be to declare the directive inside an existing element. For example:

```
<div sample-data="exp"></dir>
```

And in javascript:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.directive('sampleData', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        template: '<div>Sample Div,To test angular Directives</div>'
    };
});
```

Please see the lower cased version of `sampleData`.

Comment: Thanks for answering.The question has already been answered  25 min ago before u with the same answer that you have provided...So please check the answers before answering and upvote them..